# Selecting options in a bootstrap dropdown menu in selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a specific row in a dropdown-menu but my xpath or CSS are not able to identify the object... What would your xpath or CSS be? your help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```html
<div id="WBnavbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
Renew 
<span class="caret"/>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
<li>
<a onclick="" href="link1">Renew option1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a onclick="" href="link2">Renew option2</a>
</li>
<li>
<a onclick="" href="link3">Renew option3</a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
Update Address 
<span class="caret"/>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
<li>
<a onclick="" href="link4">Update Address Option1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a onclick="" href="link5">Update Address Option2</a>
</li>
<li>
<a onclick="" href="link6">Update Address Option3</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
    public void selectValue(WebElement list, final String value) {
        List<WebElement> options = list.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

        for (WebElement option : options) {
            if (option.getText().contains(value)) { //Here you have select contains or some thing 
                option.click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

WebElement ul = driver.findElement(By.className("dropdown-menu"));
selectValue(ul, "Option1");
```

Only works for input type=select
Create a `WebElement` and convert it to a `Select` element (org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select), use `Select` methods to select your option. This only works with html select elements.

```
Select element = new Select(webelement);
element.selectByValue(value);
```

Comment: what is your xpath would be?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.className("dropdown-menu")) .. If there are multiple menus then  you may have to findElement by WBnavbar and on that element find this dropdown-menu

Comment: Sorry this will not work  for "ul"   Select works only for input type=select

Comment: Thank you for your help Raghu. But it's not working for my case. Somehow selenium is not able to locate any element on the page even xpaths are correct and elements are highlighted...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `Selenium 3.141.59`. This is for `Bootstrap's` DropDown Button. I am guessing it may help in this case also.

**I notice that this works better when the mouse is not over the browser**

```
    WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15); //Use WebdriverWait to give the drop down menu time to display
    WebElement selectIssnIsbnButton = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("evt-searchTypeButton")));//Find the button assoicated with the dropdown menu.
    selectIssnIsbnButton.click(); //Click that button
    WebElement list = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("evt-searchType"))); //Wait until the dropdown list items are visible. This finds the list <ul>
    List<WebElement> menuItems = list.findElements(By.tagName("a"));//This finds all the <a> in the list
    System.out.println("size: " + menuItems.size());

    //loop through the <a> and click the one need. Then break.
    for (WebElement item : menuItems) {
        System.out.println("item: " + item.getText());
        if (item.getText().equals("ISSN/ISBN")) {
            item.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

> A second solution

```
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    WebElement selectIssnIsbnButton = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("evt-searchTypeButton")));
    selectIssnIsbnButton.click();
    List<WebElement> list = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'evt-searchType')]//li//a")));  //driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'evt-searchType')]//li//a"));
    System.out.println("list size: " + list.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("dropdown: " + list.get(i).getText());
        if (list.get(i).getText().equals("ISSN/ISBN")) {
            list.get(i).click();
            break;
        }
    }
```