# How can I find and click on dropdown element with XPath in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, element

I'm testing some code and want to know how can I find this dropdown element?
I'd like to choose the option "Sair"

[Dropdown Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC6hX.png)

[Dropdown Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMSXV.png)

[Dropdown Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmPQO.png)

[Dropdown Options Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPdFY.png)

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem ? Please give a status for future people visiting your question looking for answers

Answer (score 0):

what you want is select an option in a Bootstrap Dropdown combo right ?
Have a look at that other question with pretty accurate answer : [Selecting options in a bootstrap dropdown menu in selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36724042/2143734)

For your xpath, it would be something like

```
ul/li/a[text() = 'Sair']
```